# Java why does cell keep changing colors

Tags: java, oop

Hello sorry I'm very weak in programming.
I'm trying to make my Box each a different shade of green. However, when I implement my code it keeps changing colors even when my box loop is finished.
The finished product is suppose to be a tetris with boxes that have different color of green.
So tetris class creates a lot of boxes in a array .
The method for the tetris is to create each box having its unique position of i and j

```
import javax.swing.*;
        import java.awt.*;

       class Main extends JFrame {
  
       class App extends JPanel {
      
      Grid grid;

      public App() {
          setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 720));
          grid = new Grid();
      }

      @Override
      public void paint(Graphics g) {
          grid.paint(g, getMousePosition());
      }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Main window = new Main();
      window.run();
  }

  private Main() {
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      App canvas = new App();
      this.setContentPane(canvas);
      this.pack();
      this.setVisible(true);
  }

  public void run() {
      while (true) {
          this.repaint();
      }
  }
}

import java.awt.*;

class Grid {
  //fields
  Cell[][] cells = new Cell[20][20];

  // constructor
  public Grid(){
      for(int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++){
              cells[i][j] = new Cell(10+35*i,10+35*j);
          }
      }
  }

  // methods
  public void paint(Graphics g, Point mousePos){
      for(int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++){
              cells[i][j].paint(g, mousePos);
          }
      }
  }
}

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

class Cell extends Rectangle {
  // fields
  int random_int;
  int minyellow = 50;
  int maxyellow = 100;
  static int size = 35;

  //constructors
  public Cell(int x, int y){
      super(x,y,size,size);
  }

  //methods

  void paint(Graphics g, Point mousePos){      
      int random_int = (int)(Math.random() * (maxyellow - minyellow + 1) + minyellow);
      this.random_int=random_int;
      
      if(contains(mousePos)){
          g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
      } 
       else {
         
          g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(255, random_int, 60));
      
      }
      g.fillRect(x,y,size,size);
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawRect(x,y,size,size);
  }

  public boolean contains(Point p){
      if (p != null){
          return super.contains(p);
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You pick a random colour in `paint`. That means you get a new random colour each time the cell is painted.

Comment: Yes that was intended, however when i run the program it will not show a static grid with multiple cells with different color, but will keep changing color of the cells infinitely. i'm guessing it has to do with the repaint command, but i do not know how to exit it after drawing the 20 by 20 grid

Comment: "Yes that was intended"—The exact problem you are asking about is intended?

Comment: oh i see the problem, is there a way to get random shade of yellow without putting it in the paint method

Comment: You could set the `random_int` variable once, in `Cell`'s constructor, and not in the paint method.

Comment: Thank you so much, real life saver.... THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem in your code is that you pick the random number for your colour inside `Cell`'s `paint` method, so every time it is painted, it gets a new random colour.

For a cell to have a stable colour, the simplest fix is to set `random_int` once, in the constructor, and not update it.

```
public Cell(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y, size, size);
    random_int = (int) (Math.random() * (maxyellow - minyellow + 1) + minyellow);
}

void paint(Graphics g, Point mousePos) {      
    if (contains(mousePos)) {
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    } 
    else {
        g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(255, random_int, 60));
    }
    g.fillRect(x,y,size,size);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x,y,size,size);
}
```